# Android Save Instance - Best Practice

Tags: android, variables, bundle, instance

So in order to save the instance of my Fragment, I use a Bundle which I save in onSaveInstanceState and restore in onActivityCreated. Now I'm wondering what the best practice is:

1) Have a bundle where you store variables in, and use/update as required in your code. This way saving and restoring states' code is very short. Something like this:

```
private Bundle mDataValues = new Bundle();

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if ( (savedInstanceState != null) && (savedInstanceState.getBundle("mDataValues") != null) ) {
        this.mDataValues = savedInstanceState.getBundle("mDataValues");
}

public void someFunction() {
    if (this.mDataValues == null) {
        // Should not be possible on the times we call this function
        return;
    }
    usernameView.setText(mDataValues.getString(Constants.BUNDLE_KEY_USERNAME));
    personnameView.setText(mDataValues.getString(Constants.BUNDLE_KEY_PERSONNAME));
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putBundle("mDataValues", mDataValues);
}
```

2) Have a bunch of variables declared in the fragment, and use these in your code. Something like this:

```
private String mUsername;
private String mPersonname;

@Override
public void onActivtyCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if ( savedInstanceState != null ) {
        mUsername = savedInstanceState.getString("username");
        mPersonname = savedInstanceState.getString("personname");
    }

}

public void someFunction() {
    usernameView.setText(mUsername);
    personnameView.setText(mPersonname);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("username", mUsername);
    outState.putString("personname", mPersonname);
}
```

The amount of variables above is of course a lot less than in the actual code written. So what is the best practice? Or are both viable in specific situations?

Comment: First one is better when you has serval attr.

Comment: Put it into the backstack and when user presses the back button, it will be popped from the back stack. This option is when you want your fragments with back functionality just like activities.

When the activity is created, you can also just let your app add/replace the container with the desired fragment

Comment: 'I use a Bundle which I save in onSaveInstanceState'. Where?

Comment: @greenapps outState.putBundle("mDataValues", mDataValues);
mDataValues is a Bundle, no?